# Tile error: Expected a homogeneous image collection, but an image with an incompatible band was encountered

Tags: google-earth-engine

It is a very simple script, but I cannot figure it out.

The script is to create a list containing the constant images from 0 to 32, and then display them.

```
var test = ee.List.sequence(0,32).map(function(i){return ee.Image.constant(i); });
print(test);
Map.addLayer(ee.ImageCollection(test),{},'test');
```

The error is:

```
test: Tile error: Expected a homogeneous image collection, but an image with an incompatible band was encountered. Mismatched type for band 'constant':
Expected: Type<Float<0.0, 0.0>>.
  Actual: Type<Float<1.0, 1.0>>.
          Image ID: 1
This band might require an explicit cast.
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`ee.Image.constant()` produces an image band whose *pixel type* holds exactly the number you gave it. An ImageCollection requires each image's bands to have the same types as the other images.

Therefore, you need to give the images a more general type that is the same for all of them, such as

```
return ee.Image.constant(i).toFloat();
```

to be simple, or

```
return ee.Image.constant(i).cast({'constant': ee.PixelType('int', 0, 31)});
```

to give it the type exactly wide enough.

Comment: Dear Reid, your solution absolutely works. But I woder why the `.int()`  (or int8(), int16()... ) does not work, which cast the images to integer instead of float?

Comment: @NickCarraway I tried using `ee.Image.constant(i).int()` and it did not give an error in the example. What are you seeing? (If complex, this might be best posted as a separate question.)

Comment: Perhaps the error was caused by my typo, because it didn't give an error this time. Thanks for your answer.