# Band Names in Google Earth Engine - Modis LST data

Tags: google-earth-engine, modis, band, layer-name

I am working with some modis LST data, and am running into the following problem:

I am running two functions on the data, which I will need to combine later. For that reason, the band names need to be the same. When I run the code below however, one output has band [LST_DAY_1km], and one has band [constant]. This obviously doesnt add up, and I am confused where the problem is coming from, given I'm using the same input data.

See code below:

```
    // Use the expression function to generate scaled LST.

var scaledlst1 = lst.map(function (lst) {
  return lst.expression(
    '(lst/30)',{
      'lst': lst.select('LST_Day_1km')
    });

});

Map.addLayer(scaledlst1, {band:'LST_Day_1km' ,max: 1 , min: 0}, 'scaledlst1');

//

var scaledlst2 = lst.map(function (lst) {
  return lst.expression(
    '(2.5-(0.05*lst))',{
      'lst': lst.select('LST_Day_1km')
    });

});

Map.addLayer(scaledlst2, {band:'LST_Day_1km', max: 1 , min: 0}, 'scaledlst2');
```

Does anyone have any suggestions as to why this might be?

My next step is to take the minimum value per pixel between the two products:

```
//select images

var ListOfImages1 = scaledlst1.toList(scaledlst1.size())
var ListOfImages2 = scaledlst2.toList(scaledlst2.size())


var LST = ee.Image(ListOfImages1.get(0))
var LST2 = ee.Image(ListOfImages2.get(0))


//Take min value
var scaledLST = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages([LST,LST2]).min()

Map.addLayer(scaledLST, {max: 1 , min: 0}, 'Scaled LST');
```

Which yields the following error:

Scaled LST: Tile error: Expected a homogeneous image collection, but an image with incompatible bands was encountered:
First image type: 1 bands ([LST_Day_1km]).
Current image type: 1 bands ([constant]).
Image ID: 1
Some bands might require explicit casts.

Comment: Please [Edit] to include error messages as text in the body of the Question. Images are not searchable (or legible on all devices).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the "constant" band name arises because the second expression begins with a constant, which is treated as a [single-band constant image](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/image_math). Note that with a small adjustment to your code, the resulting band names in `scaledls2` is the expected "LST_Day_1km":

```
// Select a geometry for reproducibility
var geometry = ee.FeatureCollection('TIGER/2016/Counties')
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('NAME', 'Waldo'));
print(geometry);
// Explicitly call dataset
var MOD = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MOD11A1");
var lst = MOD.filterDate("2019-01-01", "2019-02-01").filterBounds(geometry);
// First scaling operation
var scaledlst1 = lst.map(function (lst) {
  return lst.expression(
    '(lst / 30)',{
      'lst': lst.select('LST_Day_1km')
    });

});
print("scaledlst1",scaledlst1);
Map.addLayer(scaledlst1, {band:'LST_Day_1km' ,max: 1 , min: 0}, 'scaledlst1');

// Second scaling operation
var scaledlst2 = lst.map(function (lst) {
  return lst.expression(
    '(lst * (-0.05)) + 2.5',{
      'lst': lst.select('LST_Day_1km')
    });

});
print("scaledlst2",scaledlst2);
Map.addLayer(scaledlst2, {band:'LST_Day_1km', max: 1 , min: 0}, 'scaledlst2');
```

Also note Kevin Reid's discussion [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/355295/67264) on the tile error issue and how to work around that.

Comment: Thank you, that did remedy the band name issue! Ive taken a jab at the discussion you linked, but am receiving an error saying: Scaled LST: Layer error: Image.constant: Invalid Image.constant type. I tried: var LST = ee.Image.constant(ListOfImages1.get(0)).toFloat();

Comment: Hmm, sounds like fodder for another question on gis.se. Folks like to limit posts to one question only around here.

Comment: Good to know! First time posting, thanks for the info!